# Hashset implementation output

Tags: java

For this block of code I am asked to explain how the output would be different from the input:

Does the difference have to do with a string object being passed in and a string literal being returned?

```
import java.util.*;

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String a : args)
            if (!s.add(a))
                System.out.println("here: " + a);

        System.out.println(s.size() + " there: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read what `add` method of `Set` does. And please add the missing `{`, so the code compiles.

Comment: @Aarce Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add(..)` function returns false if a string with the same contents was present in the `HashSet` (and the duplicate is obviously not added). Hence, the `if (!s.add(a))` will be true, if duplicate strings are present in the `args`; `s.size() <= args.length`.

Answer (score 0):

The first output will print duplicate input parameters in order they are passed,  because elements are added to the set, whose `boolean add(E e)` method will return false if an element is already present.

The second output will print the size of the resulted set, which may differ from the size of the original parameter list as the set will contain only unique elements, and then all the elements, very likely in completely different order.

From HashSet documentation:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.